# Giving Options to the User and then Displaying the chosen option

Tags: reactjs

So, i have just started working on React and i have a doubt. So, i want to create two different forms and then allow user to fill one form by selecting that form. So, i have created both the forms now how do i create a page where i give options to the user to choose one and after the user chooses first option, then the first option form displays. How do i do that? I have created both the forms, now i just need help with how to link those two forms to the pages where i am giving option to the user. 
So, do i need to create a third component like the other two containers. Those forms are basically are two different containers. So, how do i work on the third container?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firs you need two radio inputs that user will select them and a variable that will hold the selected value and will change on onChange:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState("first");

function onChange({ target }) {
  setSelected(target.value);
}

return {
  <label>
    <input value="first" onChange={onChange} type="radio" name="forms" checked={selected === "first"} />
    First Form
  </label>
  <label>
    <input value="second" onChange={onChange} type="radio" name="forms" checked={selected === "second"}  />
    Second Form
  </label>
}
```

Then you need to show forms based on what the selected value is:

```
{selected === "first" && <FirstForm />}
{selected === "second" && <SecondForm />}
```

So when selected is 'first' it will show FirstForm component otherwise when its 'second' it will show 'SecondForm'.

So the final `MainComponent` will be like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FirstForm from './first-form.js';
imprt SecondForm from './second-form.js';

function MainComponent() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("first");

  function onChange({ target }) {
    setSelected(target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Select Form</h1>
      <label>
        <input value="first" onChange={onChange} type="radio" name="forms" checked={selected === "first"} />
        First Form
      </label>
      <label>
        <input value="second" onChange={onChange} type="radio" name="forms" checked={selected === "second"} />
        Second Form
      </label>
      {selected === "first" && <FirstForm />}
      {selected === "second" && <SecondForm />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do i need to import those forms to the main component?

Comment: So, like those two components are separately created. So, i will create this component independently and then import those components? Am i going right?

Comment: @Sid Of course you need to import them. Because if you dont import you wont be able to use them. Yep thats right. Check the updated answer, I added imports too!